# BeautifulSoup cannot read file despite correct charset

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encoding

I am trying to open a file that has a utf-8 metatag with BeautifulSoup using utf-8, yet I get a parsing error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser", from_encoding="utf-8")
```

File header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>
   Logs
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
```

Error:

> $ python3.6 dom.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dom.py",
> line 56, in 
> soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser", from_encoding="utf-8")   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py", line 309, in
> **init**
> markup = markup.read()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
> return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position
> 152902: ordinal not in range(128)

How should I proceed in debugging this?
Thanks

Comment: Try: `soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8").read(), "html.parser")`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't open the file correctly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser", from_encoding="utf-8")
```

OR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser", from_encoding="utf-8")
f.close()
```